# Graph API PHP usage limit possible solution?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My php app is integrated with Facebook's Graph API.  I recently conducted load testing and found out that I hit the 600 requests per 600 seconds limit rather easily with a low number of users(1 large single batch request per user).  In order to make my app work I feel that I would need to rely on user tokens(client side) instead of my single app token(server side).

My question is: Is what I want to do even possible and does my proposed solution make sense and how could I implement it?

1) Use JS sdk to login the user to FB and obtain a user token

2) Pass the user token to the php side

3) Make the graph api call using the user token

I am reading http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/.
It says "this allows you to connect the user to your site or app using the JavaScript SDK (FB.login or the Login Button) and then call Platform APIs from server-side PHP without doing additional work".  Does this mean using the user token or app token?

I am not looking to be spoon fed code, but could someone please point me in the right direction and give their opinion on my proposed solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your proposed solution will not have any problem, just try it.

Comment: FYI: You can get a user access token via the server-side login flow as well. (In _what way_ you get it, does not matter at all.)